# How to download programmatically a folder from a server to the phone?? 

Tags: android, download, connection, directory

Hey,
I would like to download a whole folder to the phone, not just 1 file..
How can I do that in my application?  Is it even possible ? Thanks.

Comment: did you ever seen this functionality in desktop ?

Comment: A folder from where? SAMBA, FTP?

Comment: @HaMMeR The folder is from FTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do that. You'll have to download one file at a time, and create the folder(s) from your app.

If you're using FTP, you could use the FTP classes in [Apache commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/).

Comment: Do I have to know the files names? or is there a way to download ALL the files that exist in the folder

Comment: If you are using FTP, you can issue a `LIST` command, but the results are not standardized. Your server should generate a manifest (whose name is known) and/or you could use an FTP library

Answer (score 1):

You can't download a whole folder by just its name,, but you can loop over all the files in the folder and download them one by one

Comment: Do I have to know the files names? or is there a way to download ALL the files that exist in the folder